# Unity settings overlapping other settings error

Tags: unity, settings, volumetric-light

In my unity game, I am using the amazing unity asset aura volumetric lighting and when I add its script into my camera this happens:

[image]

Yeah... I can't see anyone else who got these settings overlapping each other on the stack exchange or anywhere else. Not only does it overlap but I can actually change its settings and the camera settings if I click in the right areas! I restarted unity but it still doesn't fix anything. Please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the order of the components change anything?

Comment: no... I tried moving it up and down as well as closing it and opening it but it doesnt change. I am reinstalling the asset right now so hopefully that fixes even though it takes a very long time to import like 20 minutes to 1 hour!

Comment: It doesnt fix it

Comment: Have you contacted the makers of this asset to ask if they're aware of the issue or have any recommended fixes/workarounds?

Comment: After any attempts of trying to solve this issue I just started using a different one which works even better! It is really useful. It is a volumetric light script from a brackeys video. I thought i would never see the day but i did!

Comment: Want to post an Answer explaining the steps of your new solution?

Comment: I just got a new asset that wasnt aura and deleted aura, it didnt really fix the issue